# Image not pointing (rotating) where you touch

Tags: java, android

So I'm making android game and I'm trying to make my weapon point where you touch.

EDIT: Still not working, no errors, but it doesn't rotate.

```
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Vector3 touch, OrthographicCamera camera) {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        touch.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touch);

        float finalX = Assets.sprite_guy.getX() - touch.x;
        float finalY = Assets.sprite_guy.getY() - touch.y;      

        float rotationInRad = (float) Math.atan2(finalY, finalX);
        float rotationInDeg = (float) Math.toDegrees(rotationInRad);


        Assets.sprite_guy.setRotation(rotationInDeg);

    }
    return true;
}
```

This is in Assets.java

```
    texture_guy = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Guy.png"));
    texture_guy.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    sprite_guy = new Sprite(texture_guy);
    sprite_guy.flip(false, true);
```

EDIT: Still haven't solved this out.

Comment: 1/ `radToDeg` is not `radiansToDegrees`, how is anyone supposed to know which of your code or your error message is accurate? 2/ `MathUtils.radiansToDegrees` is a constant, not a function. Read its documentation. please.

Comment: Whoops don't know why I put it that way, I thought it was the same thing so I just replaced it with that, anyways I still got the problem with radToDeg.

Comment: Still not working, there is no errors, but it doesn't rotate.

Comment: Assets.sprite_guy what is the type of this?

Comment: It's now in main post

Comment: Still haven't solved this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using xml with two different positioned images like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.    com/apk/res/android">

     <item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/    weapon_clicked" />


  <item
android:state_focused=
"true"
android:drawable="@drawable/weapon_clicked"/>

     <item
android:drawable="@drawable/    weapon_original" /> 
 </selector>
```

Comment: I don't want to mess with this, I just want to do it with java.